# Why are some videos not available in mobile?

Tags: youtube, mobile, youtube-watch-later

Why are some videos not available in mobile in YouTube?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screen clip showing video is "Not Available on Mobile"]

Comment: Is it dependent on the connection type? 3G / WiFi ...?

Answer (score 1):

Copyright owners can decide whether or not they want to make a video available on mobile. In this case, it appears they decided that they didn't make it available.